# react-create-app/flow-type doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, flowtype, recompose

When i write functional components and describe prop types as flow it doesn't recognize that. Example below should throw an error because `props.some` isn't a string it is actually a number.

```
// @flow

import React from 'react'
import {compose, withProps} from 'recompose'

const
  App = (props: {
    some: string
  }) => <div className='App'>{props.some}</div>

export default compose(
  withProps({
    some: 42
  })
)(App) //Response => No Errors
```

In other cases such `(e: string) => e; e(42); // => Error` flow-type works fine.

My .flowconfig is only after flow init.

Comment: please provide a clear description of what is "not working correctly"

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet sorry for that it is my first question on stackoverflow and English is not my native language. I rewrote question a little.  Іs it clear now?

Comment: Much better, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is getting the types for the recompose library. Without that, Flow has no way to know what the type of the wrapping component should be. Have you [installed a libdef](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) for recompose?

Answer (score 0):

Installed `flow-typed` helped. And there is an [article](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/tree/master/types) of how to install flow-type with recompose